# Jquery doesn't work with sharePoint and internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I am really stuck, I created a webpage and uploaded it into sharePoint and the page works fine in all browsers except internet explorer,

I just get this error

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

I have tried every fix in the internet but it didn't work, to make sure that the only problem is with Jquery I did the following, I created a page with the following simple script :

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

after I uploaded this file ,I still get the same error, I have been trying to solve this but no results, anyone expert with sharePoint, or with these browser compatibility issues that can contribute anything, I am using internet explorer 11 enterprise mode.

Comment: Why are you creating new websites with sharepoint?

Comment: because my company uses sharePoint

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is likely configured to display your SharePoint site in compatibility mode, which emulates IE8 and thus uses the nonstandard `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`.

For compatibility with IE8, you can use an older version of jQuery. The last version of jQuery that works with IE8 is 1.X, which you can download from the [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/).

Comment: the problem is that, I am using D3 library which uses a higher version of JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="**" />` from you page? If you did, I would advise you to put it back. I have had lots of trouble because of the meta tag. By the way, if SharePoint 2010 replace ** -> **IE=8** or if SharePoint 2013 replace ** -> **IE=10**.

Also, have you tried using another version of jQuery, maybe https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js?

I found this in another post, it could be useful:

> This unfortunately breaks other things. Here is the fix I found on another site that seemed to work for me:
>
> I'd say leave the X-UA-Compatible as "IE=8" and add the following code to the bottom of your master page:

```
<script language="javascript">
    /* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
    if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
    {
        UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
    } 
</script>
```

> This fixes a bug in core.js which incorrectly calculates that sets UserAgentInfo.strBrowse=3 for IE11 and thus supporting addEventListener. I'm not entirely sure on the details other than that but the combination of keeping IE=8 and using this script is working for me. Fingers crossed until I find the next IE11/SharePoint "bug"!

Comment: i also tried adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="**" />